# How can I do this animation?

Tags: iphone, animation, sdk

How can I do this animation? (check picture):
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/534/img0022b.png/
I don't know what they call it, so I couldn't google it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What i guess is this animation will be called as `Tooltip` animation or tooltip view..  we already have previous question on tooltip ... please go through that

[how to open a new uiview like a popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419053/how-to-open-a-new-uiview-like-a-popup)

I think you can achieve all height and width and position to set the views...