# Scaling webview animation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, calayer, cabasicanimation

I have webview in a viewcontroller of size 50x50 (width and height). And I have button to scale/stretch the width and height of the webview. So whenever the button is pressed, I want to increase the height and width of the webview. I want to acheive this along with the animation.
I have tried using the following code , but it is not working.

```
        CALayer* simple = [[CALayer alloc]init];
        simple = webView.layer;
        CATransform3D currentTransform = simple.transform;
        CATransform3D scaled = CATransform3DScale(currentTransform, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
        simple.transform = scaled;
        [simple setNeedsDisplay];
```

Please tell me how to scale a webview .

Comment: Try to explain question properly.then you may get your answer.

Comment: @Deepesh. PLease find the updated question

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/13250432/1106035

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
-(IBAction) incresethegeight:(id)sender
{



    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:1.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{ self.view.alpha = 1; }
                     completion:^(BOOL fin){[self  addHeight ];}];
}

-(void) addHeight
{  float height = webview.frame.size.height;

    CALayer* simple = [[CALayer alloc]init];
    simple = webview.layer;
    CATransform3D currentTransform = simple.transform;
    CATransform3D scaled = CATransform3DScale(currentTransform, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    simple.transform = scaled;
    [simple setNeedsDisplay];
  // or  
//   [webview setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320, height +30)];


}
```