# subView animation showing like POPView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewanimation

I tried to show subView animation like pop view, but I know only like this:

```
twobuttonView = [[UIView alloc] init];
twobuttonView.frame = CGRectMake(300, 60, 80, 100);
[self.view addSubview:twobuttonView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8
                 animations:^{
                     twobuttonView.frame = CGRectMake(220, 50, 100, 80); // its final location
                 }];
twobuttonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

but I need like this:

[image]

Comment: Add your code on UIButton touch up inside method.

Comment: @milanpanchal my code only subview animation like move to one place to other but i need animation Like POPUPView So Please give me any idea

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419053/how-to-open-a-new-uiview-like-a-popup

Comment: Can you provide GIF animation that you want?